# Pascal Counting the number of words in a line

Tags: char, pascal

I am trying to write a program that will count the number of words in each line. But the loop is not interrupted by a newline.

`

```
program StringSymbols;
var
   c  : char;
   i : integer;
begin
   i := 1;
   c := ' ';
   writeln('Enter your string');
 while c <> '#13' do
   begin
      read(c);
      if c = ' ' then i := i + 1;
   end; 
   writeln('count words: ', i)
end.
```

`

Please tell me how to write correctly. It is important that it was character-by-character reading.

Comment: Check your algorithm: Do you want to count the _number of space characters_ (as your code suggests) or do you want to count the number of _consecutive_ series of _non-space_ characters (as your question title suggests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character literal #13 for Carriage-Return should not be placed inside apostrophes, as then you got a three letter string.

```
read(c);
while (c <> #13) and (c <> #10) do
begin
    if c = ' ' then inc(i);
    read(c);
end;
```

Comment: Due to operator precedence, you would need to enclose `c <> #13` and `c <> #10` in parentheses.

Comment: In my opinion `i := i + ord(c = ' ');` is more idiomatic for Pascal.

Comment: @TomBrunberg of course, I am spoiled with java. Corrected

Comment: @KaiBurghardt I admit having more Modula-2 experience, a descendant of Pascal. But INC is standard Pascal AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way to test whether a file is at end of line is to use the eoln function. So in your program, this would be

```
while not eoln do
   begin
      read(c);
      if c = ' ' then i := i + 1;
   end;
```